# HTML content not fully showed in IE11

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, html

```css
  <style type="text/css">


 .modal 
 {
   /*padding: 5px 50px 10px 100px;*/
  /*position:relative;*/
 display:inline-flexbox;
 
 }

      .modal-content {
  /*width: 400px;
        height: 150px;  

 /*position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;*/
  display:inline-flexbox;
      }



#divAttachFileDialog{

 /*white-space: nowrap;*/
 /*display:inline-flexbox;*/
    /*overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:clip;*/

}

     .Themebutton:hover
    {
    
    background-color: #1190CA;  
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;    
    font-size: 14px;
    color: White;
      cursor:pointer;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
     
    }
 .Themebutton
    {
    
    background-color:#3A5A81; 
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;    
    }
     </style>
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MT32_Inbox_AttachFile_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE11" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="/js/JQ/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/JQ/jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="../../../js/AttachFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
       
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id='divAttachFileDialog' class="modal" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:small;">
<b >Follow the below steps to Attach Maximum of 3 Files with every file size upto 5MB:</b><br /><br />
1.Click on 'Browse' button to select file you wish to attach.With Every browse action you can select one file at a time.<br />
2.Once Browse of upto 3 file is done,Click on 'Attach' to list the files<br />
3.Finally Click on 'Done' to complete file attachment.<br /><br />
    <b>Attach Files<br /></b>
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lblFileUploadMessage" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label></p>
    <div runat="server" id="divUpload" style="display: block">
                            </div>
<div class="modal-content">
    <div id="inputsPlace">
<asp:FileUpload ID="ComposeMailMultipleFileUpload" runat="server"  class="multi"  accept="txt|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|xls|doc|docx|xlsx|ppt|pptx|rtf|pdf|zip" maxlength="3" onchange="return CheckAttached();" onclick="return checkfilenumber();"/>
        </div>

<br />
<table><tr><td>
<asp:Button ID="btnAttachMultipleFiles" runat="server" Text="Attach" onclick="btnAttachMultipleFiles_Click" 
OnClientClick ="return CheckAttached();" CssClass="Themebutton" Height="25px" Width="120px"/></td><td>
 
<input type="button" value="Done" id="btnSaveFiles" onclick ="CloseMe();" runat="server" disabled="disabled" class="Themebutton" 
style="height:25px;width:120px"/></td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="Clear All" id="btnClear" onclick ="OnClearData();" class="Themebutton" style="height:25px;width:120px"/>
            </td>
            </tr></table>
            <br /><b>Note:</b><br />Use 'Remove' button to discard the file if any selected.<br />Use 'Clear All' to remove all attachment.<br /> Allowed File Extensions -
        <br />
        txt, jpeg, jpg, gif, png, xls, doc, docx, xlsx, ppt, pptx, rtf, pdf.
        <br />
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileCount" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileNameDisplay" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnInboxsizeused" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnFiles" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBrowseCount" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have wriiten an html code in the aspx page which will be viewing in the dialog box. The content is not fully viewed in IE expect the version 7. 
Is there any posibility to fix this ?

Below is the code and problem snap

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE11" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="/js/JQ/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/JQ/jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="../../../js/AttachFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
     <style type="text/css">


 .modal 
 {
     position:absolute;

 }

        .modal-content {
    position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;

        }



#divAttachFileDialog{

 /*white-space: nowrap;*/
 /*display:inline-flexbox;*/
       /*overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:clip;*/

}

     .Themebutton:hover
    {

    background-color: #1190CA;  
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;    
    font-size: 14px;
    color: White;
      cursor:pointer;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;

    }
 .Themebutton
    {

    background-color:#3A5A81; 
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;    
    }
     </style>    
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id='divAttachFileDialog' class="modal" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:small;">
<b >Follow the below steps to Attach Maximum of 3 Files with every file size upto 5MB:</b><br /><br />
1.Click on 'Browse' button to select file you wish to attach.With Every browse action you can select one file at a time.<br />
2.Once Browse of upto 3 file is done,Click on 'Attach' to list the files<br />
3.Finally Click on 'Done' to complete file attachment.<br /><br />
    <b>Attach Files<br /></b>
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lblFileUploadMessage" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label></p>
    <div runat="server" id="divUpload" style="display: block">
                            </div>
<div class="modal-content">
    <div id="inputsPlace">
<asp:FileUpload ID="ComposeMailMultipleFileUpload" runat="server"  class="multi"  accept="txt|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|xls|doc|docx|xlsx|ppt|pptx|rtf|pdf|zip" maxlength="3" onchange="return CheckAttached();" onclick="return checkfilenumber();"/>
        </div>

<br />
<table><tr><td>
<asp:Button ID="btnAttachMultipleFiles" runat="server" Text="Attach" onclick="btnAttachMultipleFiles_Click" 
OnClientClick ="return CheckAttached();" CssClass="Themebutton" Height="25px" Width="120px"/></td><td>

<input type="button" value="Done" id="btnSaveFiles" onclick ="CloseMe();" runat="server" disabled="disabled" class="Themebutton" 
style="height:25px;width:120px"/></td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="Clear All" id="btnClear" onclick ="OnClearData();" class="Themebutton" style="height:25px;width:120px"/>
            </td>
            </tr></table>
            <br /><b>Note:</b><br />Use 'Remove' button to discard the file if any selected.<br />Use 'Clear All' to remove all attachment.<br /> Allowed File Extensions -
        <br />
        txt, jpeg, jpg, gif, png, xls, doc, docx, xlsx, ppt, pptx, rtf, pdf.
        <br />
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileCount" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileNameDisplay" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnInboxsizeused" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnFiles" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBrowseCount" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working fine in IE7 . any property can fix the issue?
Attaching the issue image
Can anyone please help on this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @krish ! maybe change your code snippet to a `HTML\CSS\JS` snippet so we could look at the problem ourselves?

Comment: Please, replace the aspx-tags by the corresponding html and reformat your post so the horizontal scollbar will disappear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for response @Thatkookooguy . But sorry i coulnt able to understand what i need to do here?

Comment: @reporter thanks for response. couldnt understand . did i need to edit by question ?

Comment: @krish we need some sort of working example to see the problem for ourselves. You can add a **jsfiddle** or a **codepen**. The best thing is to add the **stackoverflow HTML\CSS\JS snippet** since it will appear inside your question. Here's [some documentation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). The design changed a bit but it works the same. What @reporter suggested is also important. This question doesn't actually related to `asp.net`, so removing that from the equation might help as well.

Comment: @Krish yes you have to edit your question.

Comment: Yes i added the fiddler code snippet

Comment: In snippet result i get the full screen but in my project it is breaked in the half way . if i drag i can view the remaing